# Can I use Content Builder emails in Triggered Sends from Marketing Cloud Connect?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send

I've noticed that Triggered Sends in Marketing Cloud only allows you to select emails built within the Classic Content Builder, is there a way to get Content Builder emails available?

I have many emails which utilise Dynamic Content and also data from the Data Extensions using `%%FIELD_NAME%%` tags, which from my understanding is not possible using the Classic Content Builder unless we use AMPScript.

If using Content Builder is not possible with Triggered Sends what would be the next best solution to sending emails to users when a new record is created in Salesforce custom object? Pushing the records into a Journey is possible but the most frequent I can have these emails sent would be an hour which is too long.

**EDIT:** Triggered sends are from [Salesforce using Marketing Cloud Connect](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/sending_emails/triggered_sends/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is definitely possible to use Content Builder emails in triggered sends as I'm currently doing this. When I go to *Email Studio -> Interactions -> Triggered Emails* and click on *Create*, in the "Content"-section I can select either *Classic Emails* or *Content Builder Emails* (see screenshot below).

[image: Email selection for triggered send in Email Studio]

If you don't have the possibility to select *Content Builder Emails* I guess this requires opening a support case - like so many feature activations in Marketing Cloud do.

**EDIT:**

As you added in your comment, you are using triggered sends via Markting Cloud Connect (which can be triggered on object creation or update).

With the [June 2017 release](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/june_2017_release/integrations/), Salesforce added support for Content Builder E-Mails using Marketing Cloud Connect. However, this isn't available for current customers without manually updating Marketing Cloud Connect to version 208:

> The new email selection is available to Email Sends and Triggered Sends. This release does not support using Content Builder emails with AB Tests.
>
> This feature is available to any clients utilizing the 208 version of the package.

**Workaround using Journey Builder (doesn't require Connector Update):**

However you could create a journey using Journey Builder in Marketing Cloud. This journey needs to be triggered by a Salesforce Data event with the same criteria you would define in Sales/Service Cloud when configuring your triggered send. Your journey would then be very basic as the only activity added to the canvas would be an email send activity, where you can use Content Builder emails. Note that Salesforce Data Events are not subject to the synchronization schedule you define for your data sources and are triggered immediately, so this isn't an issue.

*Documentation articles related to the Journey Builder workaround:*

- [Salesforce Data Event](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/using_the_salesforce_sales_and_service_cloud_event/)
- [Send Email Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/configuring_the_send_email_activity/)

Comment: Thanks Markus for the screenshot, I should have noted that the triggered sends are via Salesforce. Creating a triggered send in Salesforce Marketing Cloud tab only does not provide the two options as displayed in your screenshot.

Comment: I just updated my answer to include a workaround that could suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[image]the June 2017 release notes, documentation [here](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/june_2017_release/integrations/) mentions that Content Builder emails can now be used in Sales Cloud Triggered Sends using Marketing Cloud Connect.

Thanks
Nikhil

Comment: Thanks Nikhil for clarifying, is this across all sends? I don't see it available for Triggered Sends

Comment: Are you able to see the Content Builder emails for Email Sends(non Triggered Sends) in Salesforce ?

Comment: Hi, yes the Content Builder Emails are available for Triggered Sends. Please refer the screen shot above in the answer.

Comment: You might need to upgrade you connector app in Sales Cloud, if these are not available